# Render Two Components at First Run

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm working on a small react app with four components: Main, Nav, Timer, and Countdown. When I run it (open a new tab and load the app, not refresh), I want this app to render Main and Timer components simultaneously, but the app only renders Main Component and I see a blank page with only Nav component has been rendered.

I tried using IndexRoute but I got a strange error and it didn't work for me.

Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
import Main from 'Main';
import Timer from 'Timer';
import Countdown from 'Countdown';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <div>
            <Route path="/" component={Main} />
            <Route exact path="/timer" component={Timer} />
            <Route path="/countdown" component={Countdown} />
        </div>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Main Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Nav from 'Nav';

class Main extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Nav />
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Nav Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

class Nav extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="top-bar">
                <div className="top-bar-left">
                    <ul className="menu">
                        <li className="menu-text">React Timer</li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/timer" activeClassName="active-link" activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Timer</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/countdown" activeClassName="active-link" activeStyle={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Countdown</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div className="top-bar-right">
                    <ul className="menu">
                        <li className="menu-text">Created by Milad Fattahi</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default Nav;
```

The other two components contain only a simple text element.

Comment: you want to make the Main component as main page and other routes as the child of that? means rendering of other route components inside Main?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And as I said, I want to show both Main and Timer components at first run of the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndexRoute` and `hashHistory` are not available in `react-router-dom`. Make use of `Switch` to render only first matching Route. You can then have the Child Routes in the component itself.

Also when you use `Switch` , have the route with `path="/"` at last otherwise it will match it at the begining and will not render your other routes

You can configure your time component to be a child of the Main component like

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Main} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Then in Main component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Nav from 'Nav';
import {Route, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'
class Main extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <Nav />
            <Redirect to="/timer" />
            <Route exact path="/timer" component={Timer} />
            <Route path="/countdown" component={Countdown} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: I tried this but there is a problem. When I switch to Countdown component, the Nav component rendered at first run disappears.

Comment: So in router v4, in order to nest route you need to specify the route in the component itself, I have updated the code to fit your need